# scanf skipping array position

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I'm almost new to programming and I'm preparing for an Uny exam(sorry for my not really good english :

I'm learning structures (`struct`), and I have some problem with `scanf` which is supposed to insert characters in an array of the structure. But instead of inserting a char for every array space it skypes one, so if i `scanf(a-s-d-f-d)` the array results `array{a- -s- -d- -f- - d}`

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct persona
{
  char name[10];
  int eta;
  int data[3]
};
struct persona simpatico;

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &simpatico.name[i]);
    }
    for(j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        printf("%i %c \n", j, simpatico.name[j]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you provide input? Do you do "A<Enter>S<Enter>D<Enter>..." or "ASDF...<Enter>"? (I bet it's the first one)

Comment: You probably want to replace the first `for` loop with `scanf("%s9", simpatico.name);`.

Comment: i actually use the first one, A<Enter>S<Enter>D<Enter>. I have already corrected my mistake of typing all in one go. :D
I actually have no idea of what "%s9" should stand for.
BTW thanks <3

Comment: Then use `" %c"`. Note the extra space.

Comment: With the extra space it actually works as intended <3
But i don't understand why?

Comment: averything solved thanks a lot